# SQL retrieving data from 2 different table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these two table namely question and answer. 
**Question table**

```
exam_id /* unique ID
ref_number /* for numbering of question */
value /* the question */
```

**Answer table**

```
    exam_id, /*id to connect to question */
    ref_number /*identifier for what question */
    answer /*the value */
```

I used this SQL to get the fields in the database

```
SELECT exam_answer.*, exam_question.* FROM exam_question INNER JOIN exam_answer ON exam_question.exam_id = exam_answer.exam_id WHERE exam_question.exam_id =10
```

I tested using the ID 10 to get the fields, but the questions are repeating based on the number of counts of answers. Which is wrong, what I'm trying to do is to query the question and then the corresponding answer. Something like this.

```
Question 1
Answer 1,
answer 2,
answer 3
answer 4

Question 2
Answer 1,
answer 2,
answer 3
answer 4
```

Any idea on what I am missing?

Comment: You are misunderstanding how SQL produces result sets.  These are in the form of a table, with all columns having the same meaning.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the point. Can you give me an idea on how to perform the sql based on my question?

Comment: Spencer has pointed you to an error in the join, which will certainly help, But I think you have missed to point about presentation, SQL, by itself, isn't going to arrange Question and answer into one column as you have requested. SQL presents data in columns and you will deliberately get "repitition" (nb NOT! duplication) in some of those columns. Are you using PHP perhaps? presentation into that single column format should be performed by PHP (or whatever your "presentation layer" happens to be using).

Answer (score 1):

While this is generally to be considered presentation logic, I have had the need to handle this using the database.  Using `union` and creating a sort order can handle the layout.

```
select result
from (
  select exam_id, ref_number, value as result, 1 as sort_order
  from question 
  union all
  select exam_id, ref_number, answer as result, 2 as sort_order
  from answer
 ) t
order by exam_id, ref_number, sort_order
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8e0bf/5)

Comment: this is the nearest possible solution to my answer, I did tested this one but the problem is how can I display the answers in a radio button, since this query displays all at once

Comment: @user3627265 -- sounds like a completely different question to me.  You should post a new question regarding your actual problem.  If you are using something like `php`, then I couldn't recommend using the posted solution.  Handle the logic client-side in your `presentation logic`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your are missing a predicate in the `ON` clause

```
 ON exam_question.exam_id = exam_answer.exam_id 
AND exam_question.ref_number = exam_answer.ref_number
```

Based on the information given in your question, it looks like you want `ref_number` column on the answer to match the `ref_number` column on the question.

Comment: Hi, the problem is that, the question display the same count as the count of the answer, so lets say we have 2 questions and 4 answers each, the questions will display 8 times.

Comment: @user3627265: If you have two rows in questions, and there are four matching rows in answers for each question, we'd expect a total of eight rows to be returned... one row for each answer. This is the result we expect from the query. (I was thinking that you were reporting a problem regarding answers for a particular question were being matched with _all_ questions on the same exam.)